# Not getting keycode in keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onkeyup

I'm trying to add a keyup function to an input field which is added to DOM using jquery.

```
$("#testDiv").html("<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text' onkeyup='testKeyUp(this)'>");
```

I want to do some operations once user enters value in `testTextbox` and enter key is pressed.

The keyup function is like:

```
function testKeyUp(e) {
alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
}
```

The `e.keyCode` and `e.which` is returning undefined.

How can I get the keycode in keyup function? Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are assigning the element to your testKeyUp handler

Comment: Where you are calling `shippingPackageKeyValueKeyUp` function?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I have edited the question.

Comment: Try to transmit `event` into the eventHandler instead of `this`, like this - `onkeyup='testKeyUp(event)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=9e5378dbd121877215f04caa2610fc62)** is What You need.

You named the function as `testKeyUp()` and the real name of the function is `shippingPackageKeyValueKeyUp(e)`. Also you wont get `this` but `event`

JS

```
$("#testDiv").html("<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text' onkeyup='testKeyUp(event)'>");

function testKeyUp(e) {
alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are mixing different things: `pure js` and `jquery`. Using only `jquery`, you can achieve what you want with the snippet below.

```js
$("#testTextbox").on("keyup", function(e){
alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text' >
```

Using only `pure Js`

```js
function testKeyUp(e){
  alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
}
```

```html
<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text' onkeyup='testKeyUp(event)'>
```

Comment: At least one who knows that one should attach the eventhandler as the only sure way to get the event in all browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

Using inline events is complicating this. `e` is acting as `this` in the function. It would be easier to modify the code slightly to remove the inline event, and instead write it as:

```
$("#testDiv").html("<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text'>");

var textInput = document.getElementById('testTextbox');

textInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
});
```

Or

```
$("#testDiv").html("<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text'>");

$('#testTextbox').on('keyup', function(e){
alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$("#testDiv").html("<input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text'>");

var textInput = document.getElementById('testTextbox');

textInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
alert(e.keyCode+" : "+e.which);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#testTextbox").on("keyup", function(e){
    if (e.key=="Enter"){
        // Your logic here
    }
    })

    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <input id='testTextbox' name='testTextbox' type='text' >
```

As @edkeveked answered above, but I would use event.*key* instead of event.*keycode*, as keycode and which are being deprecated according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i notice that your function name for the event handler does not match the onkeyup callback name.

Make sure the two match. And secondly

```
onkeyup='testKeyUp(e)'
```